# It is possible Check-in/Check-out file from WAN in Perforce

Tags: version-control, perforce

I m new to perforce, i want to know that it possible to checkin/check out file from different domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can access your perforce server then you can check in and check out files. If it's hosted on a private internal network you will need to setup SSH or some other kind of secure access to be able to talk with the server.

Comment: SSH access may be preferable, but it is not by any means neccessary.  You can simply open the port to the server and work with P4

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes it is possible. Perforce clients work fine from outside a LAN - low bandwidth connections are not a problem.

The long answer is that you need to have some kind of VPN/SSH access into your network so you can see the server. Talk to your IT department if you have one and they'll advise you on the specific details of your network.